# Numpy could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4) into shape (2,3)

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays with different shapes, for example:

```
a = np.zeros((2, 4))
b = np.ones((2, 3))
```

And I want to perform the following operation on them:

```
x1, x2 = a.shape
b[:x1, :x2] = a[:x1, :x2]
```

I want to accomplish this with the ability to flip the shapes between `a` and `b` and have it still working, i.e.

```
a = np.zeros((2, 3)) # Note that I flipped 
b = np.ones((2, 4))  # the shapes from the previous example

x1, x2 = a.shape
b[:x1, :x2] = a[:x1, :x2]
```

can that be accomplished using native NumPy and without for loops?

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution:

```
x3, x4 = b.shape
b[:x1, :x2] = a[:x3, :x4]
```

did the trick for me.